# The POST method is not supported for this route. - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, post

I have a problem with my create post page. When I submit I get this error:

> The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.

I have no clue where it comes from as I am pretty new to Laravel.

`routes(web.php)`:

```
<?php
Route::get('/', [PagesController::class, 'index']);
Auth::routes();
Route::get('/blog', 'App\Http\Controllers\PostsController@index');
Route::get('/blog/create', 'App\Http\Controllers\PostsController@create');
Route::get('/logout', 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@logout', function (){
    return abort(404); 
});
Route::get('/home', 'App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@index');
```

Controller:

```
public function index()
    {
        return view('blog.index')
            ->with('posts', Post::orderBy('updated_at', 'DESC')->get());
    }
    public function create()
    {
       return view('blog.create');
    }
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'title' => 'required',
            'description' => 'required',
            'image' => 'required|mimes:jpg,png,jpeg|max:5048'
        ]);
        $newImageName = uniqid() . '-' . $request->title . '.' .
        $request->image->extension();
        $request->image->move(public_path('images'), $newImageName);
        Post::create([
            'title' => $request->input('title'),
            'description' => $request->input('description'),
            'slug' => SlugService::createSlug(Post::class, 'slug',
            $request->title),
            'image_path' => $newImageName,
            'user_id' => auth()->user()->id
        ]);
        return redirect('/blog')
            ->with('message', 'Je post is toegevoegd!');
    }
```

[image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDjrD.png)

Answer (score 2):

You are using `get` for all your routes... You have to use `Route::post`... Read the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing) again about this topic so you can understand it better.

Remember that using `Route::post`, `Route::get`, `Route::delete` and more, is the `method` you are allowing the route to be accessed with.

Comment: Could this be done by simply changing the Route::get to Route::post because when I do this I get an error saying: The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.

Comment: Yes, but you have a problem there, you are confusing things, which route is the one giving you problems ? You can have a GET route and a POST route, no problem with that.

Comment: I figured it out, Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

It comes from your Routes:

```
Route::get('/', [PagesController::class, 'index']);
Auth::routes();
Route::get('/blog', 'App\Http\Controllers\PostsController@index');
Route::get('/blog/create', 'App\Http\Controllers\PostsController@create');
Route::get('/logout', 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@logout', function (){
    return abort(404); 
});
Route::get('/home', 'App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@index');
```

You have GET routes, but no POST routes. You need `Route::post` in order to support POST.

Answer (score 0):

You syntax for registering the route for post method is incorrect.

It should be: `Route::post($uri, $callback);` where callback can be any function in controller layer or service layer.

If you want to register your route for multiple http verbs, you can do so using any of the below methods.

```
Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/', function () {
    //
});

Route::any('/', function () {
    //
});
```

Refer to this [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing). It explains the concept in simple terms.